# how can i find the coordinates of intersection between 2 line segments C++

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ programming language i just need to know how can i declare a set of line segments given their start and end points? is there anything like that in C++?
I have this code which reads the starting and ending points of the line segments from a text file and divides the input into 4 vectors : X_start, Y_start, X_end, Y_end.
I need to know how to use these vectors to define line segments? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::ifstream is("D:\\Task1.txt");
std::istream_iterator<double> start(is), end;
std::vector<double> numbers(start, end);
std::vector<double> X_start(start, end);
std::vector<double> Y_start(start, end);
std::vector<double> X_end(start, end);
std::vector<double> Y_end(start, end);
std::vector<double>::iterator i;
std::vector<double>::iterator j;
float left, top, right, bottom; // Bounding Box For Line Segments
left = 12;
top = 12;
right = 0;
bottom = 0;

std::cout << "Read " << numbers.size() << " numbers" << std::endl;
std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;

for (vector<double>::iterator i = numbers.begin();
                       i != numbers.end();
                       ++i)
{
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j = j+4)
{
std::cout << "elemnts of X_start " << numbers[j] << "  " <<std::endl;
X_start.push_back(numbers[j]);

}
for(int k = 1; k < numbers.size(); k = k+4)
{
std::cout << "elemnts of Y_start " << numbers[k] << " " <<std::endl;
Y_start.push_back(numbers[k]);
}
for(int l = 2; l < numbers.size(); l = l+4)
{
std::cout << "elemnts of X_end " << numbers[l] << " " <<std::endl;
X_end.push_back(numbers[l]);
}
for(int m = 3; m < numbers.size(); m = m+4)
{
std::cout << "elemnts of Y_end " << numbers[m] << " " <<std::endl;
Y_end.push_back(numbers[m]);
}
getchar();
}   
}
```

Comment: Once you have the math for finding intersections on paper, it isn't that hard to implement it, 1 hint: make a class of lines.  If you want to do it via a library, this can be found via google and in stackoverflow.

Comment: do you consider 2D or 3D? Line in 2D is described at least by two points with x,y coordinates, in 3D two points with x,y,z coordinates. How do your vectors relate to this?

Comment: @stefaanv thank u can u provide the link for these libraries please?

Comment: @piotruś it's a 2D where i define each line by x,y coordinates only

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function. Just modify it to meet your requirements.

```
class Point
{
    public:
    float x,y;
};


class LineSegment
{
    public:
    Point top;
    Point bottom;
};

Point* getIntersectionPoint(LineSegment line1,LineSegment line2)
{
    float s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    float p1_x = line1.bottom.x,p1_y = line1.bottom.y;
    float p0_x = line1.top.x,p0_y = line1.top.y;
    float p3_x = line2.bottom.x,p3_y = line2.bottom.y;
    float p2_x = line2.top.x,p2_y = line2.top.y;
    s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;     s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
    s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;     s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

    float s, t;
    s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

    if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
    {
        Point *intsPoint = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point));
        intsPoint->x = p0_x + (t * s1_x);
        intsPoint->y = p0_y + (t * s1_y);
        return intsPoint;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: why intsPoint is allocated on the heap? also please delete it to avoid memory leak

Comment: @piotruś presumably to allow the function to return null in the event of the two line segments *not* intersecting.  And seeing as the answer doesn't provide a call to the method, exactly where is your proposed delete supposed to go!?

Comment: you should return by value

Comment: Problem is what value to return. Either add a new variable flag.

Answer (score 0):

"I am very new to c++ programming language"

How new to C++? Do you understand the maths involved in what you're trying to do first?

Comment: Yes Actually i do, but i don't know how can i define a set of line segments and so on in C++, 
Math is not my problem

Comment: Is the code something you've done yourself from scratch? Or copied from somewhere (source?)

Comment: no did not copy it, am trying my best to learn C++ on my own but am just a beginner